# What is CachedBatch in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, kryo

This class was not registered with Kryo, the job was normal for a week but error came that CachedBatch class is not registered? 
What is its use case ?

Comment: You have another question on kyro etc. Is cachedBatch realted to kyro? I think not.

Comment: no, cachedbatch is not related to Kryo @thebluephantom , it was a registration error of cachedbatch with Kryo.

Comment: https://allinonescript.com/questions/45950715/spark-2-2-0-intermittently-produces-org-apache-spark-sparkexception-failed-to

Comment: May be of help, but the title of your question is not reflective

Comment: the provided link doesn't work @thebluephantom

Comment: May be this: https://allinonescript.com/questions/45950715

Comment: An error in copying, excuses.

Comment: still the same thing @thebluephantom

Comment: i saw this ok this afternoon, now not... browser issue timing server